# Strange behaviour of password fields in Firefox

Tags: 18.04, firefox

When I try to clear certain password fields in Firefox by holding backspace, only the last character gets deleted and I have to press backspace repeatedly to remove the remaining characters one by one. Also, when I try to hold any other key on keyboard, only one character is typed in. I have found out the following:

- This happens only on certain websites (e.g. Facebook and Google) while on others, the password fields work just fine (e.g. StackExchange).
- The issue seems to affect only Firefox on Ubuntu 18.04 while the same version of Firefox (61.0.1) on Ubuntu 16.04 works properly.
- The issue persists in safe mode and after Firefox refresh.

I would like to know the possible causes of this behaviour and ways how to fix/disable it.

Comment: I'm suddenly also having this issue. I think I'll just live with it for now (don't feel like messing with snap) but it's good to know I'm not the only one. Note: "rapid fire mode" is not working at all in password fields, whether you're holding backspace or a random letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the Keyboard Input Method System fixed that issue for me.

```
Settings > Region and Language > Manage Installed Languages > Keyboard input method system: (Set to XIM) and restart the machine.
```

Or, run firefox with `GTK_IM_MODULE=xim firefox`

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/cbnesc/firefox_68_password_field_blinks/

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be fixed by installing the Snap version of Firefox using commands

```
sudo apt-get remove firefox
sudo snap install firefox
```

I still don't know the cause of the described behaviour, so if someone posts a complete answer, I will gladly mark it as accepted.